# fail to connect to firebase(use preview on web server)

Tags: html

I am new in Firebase, and fail to open my first project in Preview on web server
(VS code plugin)by typing ctrl+shift+L, my web just display"Cannot GET /d:/index.html"
I have found some solution to solve it but dosen't work.

1.I have add following script

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js"></script>
```

2.I also change my apiKey,authDomain,databaseURL,storageBucket

3.I tried to change my 8080port in server.xml(C:\xampp\tomcat\conf ) to 7080port, but doesn't work.

4.I also tried both open XAMPP or close it,aren't help.

Following is my error text:

1.In web : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

2.In my XAMPP:

```
[Tomcat]    Problem detected!
[Tomcat]    Port 8080 in use by "D:\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"!
[Tomcat]    Tomcat WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
[Tomcat]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
[Tomcat]    or reconfigure Tomcat and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Are there any idea about my problem, thanks!

Comment: What is not understandable about _Port 8080 in use by..._ and _Tomcat WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!_ ?

Comment: So I remove my connector port which is 8080, but didn't work